# IONIC usando nativeAudio

Tags: ionic3

Eu estou fazendo/estudando IONIC e estou empacado em uma dúvida ao tentar da play em um áudio.

Eu montei os botões assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tentei colocar o áudio para funcionar, só que não sei como escolher apenas o do botão que foi apertado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

.html

```
 <ion-row align-items-center>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button block outline (click)="play('1')">bā</button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button block outline (click)="play('2')">bá</button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button block outline (click)="play('3')">bǎ</button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button block outline (click)="play('4')">bà</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

.ts

Esta é a parte que está errada e não sei como tocar o áudio certo do botão.

```
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('1', 'assets/audio/ba1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('2', 'assets/audio/ba2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('3', 'assets/audio/ba3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('4', 'assets/audio/ba4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('5', 'assets/audio/pa1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('6', 'assets/audio/pa2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('7', 'assets/audio/pa3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('8', 'assets/audio/pa4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('9', 'assets/audio/ma1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('10', 'assets/audio/ma2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('11', 'assets/audio/ma3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('12', 'assets/audio/ma4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('13', 'assets/audio/fa1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('14', 'assets/audio/fa2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('15', 'assets/audio/fa3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('16', 'assets/audio/fa4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('17', 'assets/audio/da1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('18', 'assets/audio/da2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('19', 'assets/audio/da3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('20', 'assets/audio/da4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('21', 'assets/audio/ta1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('22', 'assets/audio/ta2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('23', 'assets/audio/ta3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('24', 'assets/audio/ta4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('25', 'assets/audio/na1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('26', 'assets/audio/na2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('27', 'assets/audio/na3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('28', 'assets/audio/na4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('29', 'assets/audio/la1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('30', 'assets/audio/la2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('31', 'assets/audio/la3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('32', 'assets/audio/la4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('33', 'assets/audio/ga1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('34', 'assets/audio/ga2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('35', 'assets/audio/ga3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('36', 'assets/audio/ga4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('37', 'assets/audio/ka1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('38', 'assets/audio/ka2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('39', 'assets/audio/ka3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('40', 'assets/audio/ka4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('41', 'assets/audio/ha1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('42', 'assets/audio/ha2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('43', 'assets/audio/ha3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('44', 'assets/audio/ha4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('45', 'assets/audio/za1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('46', 'assets/audio/za2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('47', 'assets/audio/za3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('48', 'assets/audio/za4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('49', 'assets/audio/ca1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('50', 'assets/audio/ca2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('51', 'assets/audio/ca3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('52', 'assets/audio/ca4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('53', 'assets/audio/sa1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('54', 'assets/audio/sa2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('55', 'assets/audio/sa3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('56', 'assets/audio/sa4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('57', 'assets/audio/zha1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('58', 'assets/audio/zha2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('59', 'assets/audio/zha3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('60', 'assets/audio/zha4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('61', 'assets/audio/cha1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('62', 'assets/audio/cha2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('63', 'assets/audio/cha3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('64', 'assets/audio/cha4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('65', 'assets/audio/sha1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('66', 'assets/audio/sha2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('67', 'assets/audio/sha3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('68', 'assets/audio/sha4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
});
```

}

Aqui está completamente errado eu sei

```
  play() {
this.nativeAudio.play('1').then();
this.nativeAudio.play('2').then();
this.nativeAudio.play('3').then();
this.nativeAudio.play('4').then();
```

}

Comment: Jefferson, poste o código, pois imagem não pode ser copiado o código para teste, pode ficar fora do ar, etc...

Comment: Respondi no lugar errado mas respondi

Answer (score 0):

Está funcionando mas acho que ficou muito grande

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play1()">bā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play2()">bá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play3()">bǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play4()">bà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play5()">pā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play6()">pá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play7()">pǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play8()">pà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play9()">mā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play10()">má</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play11()">mǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play12()">mà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play13()">fā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play14()">fá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play15()">fǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play16()">fà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play17()">dā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play18()">dá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play19()">dǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play20()">dà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play21()">tā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play22()">tá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play23()">tǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play24()">tà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play25()">nā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play26()">ná</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play27()">nǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play28()">nà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play29()">lā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play30()">lá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play31()">lǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play32()">là</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play33()">gā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play34()">gá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play35()">gǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play36()">gà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play37()">kā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play38()">ká</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play39()">kǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play40()">kà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play41()">hā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play42()">há</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play43()">hǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play43()">hà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play44()">zā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play45()">zá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play46()">zǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play47()">zà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play48()">cā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play50()">cá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play51()">cǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play52()">cà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play53()">pā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play54()">pá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play55()">pǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play56()">pà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play57()">cā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play59()">cá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play60()">cǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play61()">cà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play62()">cā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play63()">cá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play64()">cǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play65()">cà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play66()">sā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play67()">sá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play68()">sǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play69()">sà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play70()">zhā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play71()">zhá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play72()">zhǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play73()">zhà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play74()">chā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play75()">chá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play76()">chǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play77()">chà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play78()">shā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play79()">shá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play80()">shǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play81()">shà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play82()">wā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play83()">wá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play84()">wǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play85()">wà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play86()">yā</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play87()">yá</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play88()">yǎ</button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block outline (click)="play89()">yà</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

Aqui continua muito grande, mas funcionando:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('1', 'assets/audio/ba1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('2', 'assets/audio/ba2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('3', 'assets/audio/ba3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('4', 'assets/audio/ba4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('5', 'assets/audio/pa1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('6', 'assets/audio/pa2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('7', 'assets/audio/pa3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('8', 'assets/audio/pa4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('9', 'assets/audio/ma1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('10', 'assets/audio/ma2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('11', 'assets/audio/ma3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('12', 'assets/audio/ma4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('13', 'assets/audio/fa1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('14', 'assets/audio/fa2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('15', 'assets/audio/fa3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('16', 'assets/audio/fa4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('17', 'assets/audio/da1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('18', 'assets/audio/da2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('19', 'assets/audio/da3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('20', 'assets/audio/da4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('21', 'assets/audio/ta1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('22', 'assets/audio/ta2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('23', 'assets/audio/ta3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('24', 'assets/audio/ta4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('25', 'assets/audio/na1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('26', 'assets/audio/na2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('27', 'assets/audio/na3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('28', 'assets/audio/na4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('29', 'assets/audio/la1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('30', 'assets/audio/la2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('31', 'assets/audio/la3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('32', 'assets/audio/la4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('33', 'assets/audio/ga1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('34', 'assets/audio/ga2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('35', 'assets/audio/ga3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('36', 'assets/audio/ga4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('37', 'assets/audio/ka1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('38', 'assets/audio/ka2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('39', 'assets/audio/ka3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('40', 'assets/audio/ka4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('41', 'assets/audio/ha1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('42', 'assets/audio/ha2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('43', 'assets/audio/ha3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('44', 'assets/audio/ha4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('45', 'assets/audio/za1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('46', 'assets/audio/za2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('47', 'assets/audio/za3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('48', 'assets/audio/za4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('49', 'assets/audio/ca1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('50', 'assets/audio/ca2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('51', 'assets/audio/ca3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('52', 'assets/audio/ca4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('53', 'assets/audio/sa1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('54', 'assets/audio/sa2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('55', 'assets/audio/sa3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('56', 'assets/audio/sa4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('57', 'assets/audio/zha1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('58', 'assets/audio/zha2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('59', 'assets/audio/zha3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('60', 'assets/audio/zha4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('61', 'assets/audio/cha1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('62', 'assets/audio/cha2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('63', 'assets/audio/cha3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('64', 'assets/audio/cha4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();

  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('65', 'assets/audio/sha1.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('66', 'assets/audio/sha2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('67', 'assets/audio/sha3.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
  this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('68', 'assets/audio/sha4.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then();
});
```

}

play1() { this.nativeAudio.play('1').then(); }
  play2() { this.nativeAudio.play('2').then(); }
  play3() { this.nativeAudio.play('3').then(); }
  play4() { this.nativeAudio.play('4').then(); }
  play5() { this.nativeAudio.play('5').then(); }
  play6() { this.nativeAudio.play('6').then(); }
  play7() { this.nativeAudio.play('7').then(); }
  play8() { this.nativeAudio.play('8').then(); }
  play9() { this.nativeAudio.play('9').then(); }
  play10() { this.nativeAudio.play('10').then(); }
  play11() { this.nativeAudio.play('11').then(); }
  play12() { this.nativeAudio.play('12').then(); }
  play13() { this.nativeAudio.play('13').then(); }
  play14() { this.nativeAudio.play('14').then(); }
  play15() { this.nativeAudio.play('15').then(); }
  play16() { this.nativeAudio.play('16').then(); }
  play17() { this.nativeAudio.play('17').then(); }
  play18() { this.nativeAudio.play('18').then(); }
  play19() { this.nativeAudio.play('19').then(); }
  play20() { this.nativeAudio.play('20').then(); }
  play21() { this.nativeAudio.play('21').then(); }
  play22() { this.nativeAudio.play('22').then(); }
  play23() { this.nativeAudio.play('23').then(); }
  play24() { this.nativeAudio.play('24').then(); }
  play25() { this.nativeAudio.play('25').then(); }
  play26() { this.nativeAudio.play('26').then(); }
  play27() { this.nativeAudio.play('27').then(); }
  play28() { this.nativeAudio.play('28').then(); }
  play29() { this.nativeAudio.play('29').then(); }
  play30() { this.nativeAudio.play('30').then(); }
  play31() { this.nativeAudio.play('31').then(); }
  play32() { this.nativeAudio.play('32').then(); }
  play33() { this.nativeAudio.play('33').then(); }
  play34() { this.nativeAudio.play('34').then(); }
  play35() { this.nativeAudio.play('35').then(); }
  play36() { this.nativeAudio.play('36').then(); }
  play37() { this.nativeAudio.play('37').then(); }
  play38() { this.nativeAudio.play('38').then(); }
  play39() { this.nativeAudio.play('39').then(); }
  play40() { this.nativeAudio.play('40').then(); }
  play41() { this.nativeAudio.play('41').then(); }
  play42() { this.nativeAudio.play('42').then(); }
  play43() { this.nativeAudio.play('43').then(); }
  play44() { this.nativeAudio.play('44').then(); }
  play45() { this.nativeAudio.play('45').then(); }
  play46() { this.nativeAudio.play('46').then(); }
  play47() { this.nativeAudio.play('47').then(); }
  play48() { this.nativeAudio.play('48').then(); }
  play49() { this.nativeAudio.play('49').then(); }
  play50() { this.nativeAudio.play('50').then(); }
  play51() { this.nativeAudio.play('51').then(); }
  play52() { this.nativeAudio.play('52').then(); }
  play53() { this.nativeAudio.play('53').then(); }
  play54() { this.nativeAudio.play('54').then(); }
  play55() { this.nativeAudio.play('55').then(); }
  play56() { this.nativeAudio.play('56').then(); }
  play57() { this.nativeAudio.play('57').then(); }
  play58() { this.nativeAudio.play('58').then(); }
  play59() { this.nativeAudio.play('59').then(); }
  play60() { this.nativeAudio.play('60').then(); }
  play61() { this.nativeAudio.play('61').then(); }
  play62() { this.nativeAudio.play('62').then(); }
  play63() { this.nativeAudio.play('63').then(); }
  play64() { this.nativeAudio.play('64').then(); }
  play65() { this.nativeAudio.play('65').then(); }
  play66() { this.nativeAudio.play('66').then(); }
  play67() { this.nativeAudio.play('67').then(); }
  play68() { this.nativeAudio.play('68').then(); }
  play69() { this.nativeAudio.play('69').then(); }
  play70() { this.nativeAudio.play('70').then(); }
  play71() { this.nativeAudio.play('71').then(); }
  play72() { this.nativeAudio.play('72').then(); }
  play73() { this.nativeAudio.play('73').then(); }
  play74() { this.nativeAudio.play('74').then(); }
  play75() { this.nativeAudio.play('75').then(); }
  play76() { this.nativeAudio.play('76').then(); }
  play77() { this.nativeAudio.play('77').then(); }
  play78() { this.nativeAudio.play('78').then(); }
  play79() { this.nativeAudio.play('79').then(); }
  play80() { this.nativeAudio.play('80').then(); }
  play81() { this.nativeAudio.play('81').then(); }
  play82() { this.nativeAudio.play('82').then(); }
  play83() { this.nativeAudio.play('83').then(); }
  play84() { this.nativeAudio.play('84').then(); }
  play85() { this.nativeAudio.play('85').then(); }
  play86() { this.nativeAudio.play('86').then(); }
  play87() { this.nativeAudio.play('87').then(); }
  play88() { this.nativeAudio.play('88').then(); }
  play89() { this.nativeAudio.play('89').then(); }